# Centering JLabel using GroupLayout

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, grouplayout

I want to group a couple check-boxes together and place some text above it (think of it like a section in a form where there's a description of what this part of the form entails and a series of check-boxes)

See attached picture for visual representation:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHELj.jpg]

My goal is to center  the word 'Miscellaneous' so it sits in the center rather than on the far left.

I've tried changing the horizontal alignment of the JLabel like so:

```
miscellaneous = new JLabel("Miscellaneous");
miscellaneous.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
```

But it hasn't seem to have helped.
I have also tried this:

```
miscellaneous = new JLabel("Miscellaneous", SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

And again with no success.

Here's the full snippet of code that generates the above attached picture:

```
    miscellaneous = new JLabel("Miscellaneous");
    movement = new JCheckBox("Movement");
    consumables = new JCheckBox("Consumables");
    layoutM = new GroupLayout(miscGroup);
    miscGroup.setLayout(layoutM);

    layoutM.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
    layoutM.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

    layoutM.setHorizontalGroup(layoutM.createSequentialGroup()
             .addGroup(layoutM.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                 .addComponent(miscellaneous)
                 .addGroup(layoutM.createSequentialGroup()
                      .addGroup(layoutM.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                              .addComponent(movement))
                      .addGroup(layoutM.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                              .addComponent(consumables))))
            );

    layoutM.setVerticalGroup(layoutM.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layoutM.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(miscellaneous))
                .addGroup(layoutM.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layoutM.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layoutM.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                        .addComponent(movement)
                                        .addComponent(consumables))))
            );
```

Any help/hints would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The GroupLayout is generally used by IDE's to generate code. We generally don't use GroupLayout because of its complexity. We code GUI's be hand because we can make the code cleaner, logical and easier to maintain, so I for one can't help. I would suggest you can easily use a `GridBagLayout` for something like this. Or another approach is to use a [Titled Border](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) on the panel instead of using the label.

Comment: @camickr Hey, thanks for your input. I've figured out the problem and it was quite a simple fix. `.addGroup(layoutM.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
                 .addComponent(miscellaneous)` is what was required. Note the `.CENTER.`. But I think you're correct, this will be too repetitive and messy for multiple sections. I will look into GridBagLayout, thanks again :)